# C++ Identify template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, c-preprocessor

I would like to know is there a way to identify template argument? For example, let say I want to initialize a variable based on template argument. Prototype example is as follow

```
template<class T> 
      void initialise(T a)
      {
        if(T==int)a=0;
        else if(T=double)a=0.0;
        else if(T=complex<double>)a=T(0.,0);
        else print("unknown type"); 
      }
```

My question is how to identify that template argument "T"? Or, do I need to take help of preprocessor directives? It might be a repetitive question, but I didn't find its answer. Any kind of suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use template specialization to do that?

Comment: Do you really need the `print`? Also note your function doesn't to anything.

Comment: No, I don't need print. It is just an example.

Comment: @musafir OK, then my answer might apply.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you would "re-set" an argument to zero using a function template:

```
template<class T> 
void initialise(T& a)
{
  a = T(); // or T{};
}
```

If you want to restrict it to arithmetic types, you can use SFINAE and [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) (floating point and integral types), plus a specialization for `std::complex`.

```
template<class T> 
typename enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void >::type
void initialise(T& a)
{
  a = T();
}

template<class T>
void initialise(std::complex<T>& a)
{
  a = T();
}
```

Comment: Probably, I choose a very bad example to present my idea. However, I get the idea to solve my actual problem from this discussion. Thank you guys,

Answer (score 1):

You can use template specializations. Something like that:

```
template<class T> 
void initialise(T a)
{
    print("unknown type"); 
}

template<> 
void initialise<int>(int a)
{
    a=0;
}

template<> 
void initialise<double>(double a)
{
    a=0.0;
}

template<> 
void initialise<complex<double>>(complex<double> a)
{
    a=complex<double>(0.,0);
}
```

Of course, those functions do not make much sense, but I guess it is due to the fact that you tried to propose a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the idea.

Comment: Overloading would be so much easier. Also, see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: Absolutely, but we must start from the OP's example and I've given a solution that still involves templates. I cannot make assumption on which is the real problem and I must ever assume that the one proposed is a minimal, simplified example.